# Getting an ID from laravel command choice

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm creating a laravel command and I want to list out all the categories I have and then once I've selected
a category I would like to get the ID, but the problem is that the categories can have duplicate names
so I'm not able to find the ID using the name.

Here is my code

```
    $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    $category = $this->choice('Select category.', $categories);
```

this gives me options that look like this

```
    [1] Category 1
    [2] Category 2
    [3] Category 3
    [4] Category 4
```

and when I pick a category I only get the name, but I can't get the ID.

Comment: in that array `key` is your id  like `$categories[1]` is 1st id name it  and it does not start with 0 means it database id not array index

Comment: @KamleshPaul - then how do I get the id?

Comment: loop over it and that key is id

Answer (score 0):

Laravel interpolates the response and return the text instead. If you wanna have the id returned, you should set the validator yourself.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion;

$question = 'Select the category:';

$choices = [
    1 => 'Category 1',
    2 => 'Category 2',
    3 => 'Category 3',
    4 => 'Category 4',
];

$question = new ChoiceQuestion($question, $choices);
$question->setValidator(function($res)
{
    // here is where laravel interpolates things, but we will only return the selected choice id.
    return $res;
});

$id = $this->output->askQuestion($question);

$text = $choices[$id];
```